# How to set a minimum distance between components in KiCad PCB Designer?

Tags: kicad

How to set a minimum distance of 1.016 mm between components in KiCad PCB Designer?

Answer (score 4):

Because you place the components yourself, there is no constraint that exactly handles this. All the constraints are to do with copper/mask/silk layers, and are found under board setup, an icon in the top left.
The closest option (I can think of) is the component courtyard, which draws (in my case) a purple outline around the part, which no other part's courtyard should cross. You can still place components closer than this, but DRC gives an error.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are no design rules that directly address this.

'minimum clearance' limits the closest approach of one copper to other copper on the board, setting that to 1.016mm might be sufficient, but this will not work if any of your parts has pads that are closer than that,.

Else you'll have to edit all the footprints of the parts you want to use to make their courtyards give 0.508mm clearance around each part, those 0.508s will then add when the parts are placed to prevent them from coming closer than 1.016mm.